# Insert a line at the end of the page in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I've a scenario in crystal report where i've 2 pages.Records are filled upto the bottom in the first page and upto the middle in the second page.

Here what i want is in the first page i want to insert a line at the end of the page and the second page i dont want since data is not completely filled.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be:

```
if PageNumber = TotalPageCount then
    true
else
    false
```

This would not show the line in case there was a single page.
Show the line on all pages but the last if there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the text object with the line you want. 
Then, right click the object, select "Format Text". On the "Common" tab, click the formula button to the right of "supress" (the button that has "x-2" and pencil on it...).
Then, insert the next formula:

```
IF PAGENUMBER = 1 
THEN FALSE
ELSE TRUE
```

Click "Save and Close", then "Ok" and that should do the work...